# Combining variables in INSERT INTO SELECT in PHP mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I know this kind of question is already answered, but it still did not solve my problem.
I have 2 tables to be inserted. The first table inserts works fine. But the second one doesn't. PHP does not throw any errors. May be my MySQL query is not properly written.

I need this fixed really quickly.
Any help in this is appreciated.

```
$numb = 0; $af_f = 0; $fn = 0; $an = 0; $nt = 0; $intn = 0; $med_name = "";

$q2 = "INSERT INTO prescriptions (mr_id, mb_id, number, af_food, fn, an, nt) ";
$q2 .= "SELECT ?, MB.id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? FROM med_batch MB INNER JOIN medicines M ON M.id = MB.med_id ";
$q2 .= "WHERE M.name = ? AND DATE(CURDATE()) < DATE_SUB(DATE(MB.exp_date), INTERVAL ? DAY) ";
$q2 .= "AND MB.stock_num > ? ORDER BY MB.arr_date LIMIT 1";
$q2 = $conn->prepare($q2) or die($conn->error);
$q2->bind_param("diiiiisii", $id, $numb, $af_f, $fn, $an, $nt, $med_name, $intn, $numb) or die($q->error);


$n = 1;
while(isset($_POST["mr-med" . $n]))
{
    $intn = 0;
    $med_name = $_POST["mr-med" . $n];
    $numb = $_POST["mr-med-num" . $n];
    $af_f = (isset($_POST["mr-af" . $n]))? 1 : 0;
    $fn = (isset($_POST["mr-fn" . $n]))? 1 : 0;
    $an = (isset($_POST["mr-an" . $n]))? 1 : 0;
    $nt = (isset($_POST["mr-nt" . $n]))? 1 : 0;
    $intn = $numb / ($fn + $an + $nt);
    $intn = ceil($intn);

    $q2->execute() or die($q2->error);
    $n = $n + 1;
}
$r = $q2->store_result();

if($q2->affected_rows > 0)
{
    echo "Successfully Added";
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: In your bind your using `d` a lot - this is for a double, should they be `i` for integer.  Not sure if it makes any different in processing though.

Comment: @NigelRen thank you for pointing that out. Changed that, but it still did not solve the problem.

Comment: You don't seem to be assigning a value to `$id` anywhere?

Comment: Column names is not a data, so seems you cant use `?` as a column name placemark. There are different escape methods for table ids and data.

Comment: @Nick     $id  is assigned a value, it is not given in this section of the code I posted.

Comment: @Deadooshka We can select static data that are not column names through `SELECT`. If I replace `?` with a value and pass the query directly in a mysql command line, it works

Comment: you have to put those escaped static expressions directly into the query string (before WHERE clause).